# position between elements in uiview

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2, xib

I can't get the position that i want in my UIview, I'm using the .xib view:

this is what I want:

[image]

So, a image as background and a IUWebView inside, I want to see the image up, down, left and right, but this is what i get:

[image]

why have I not the down margin?

Thank you in advance

Comment: you have a down margin, it is under your tab bar view which is 49 pts. you can just move up you ui elements and have maybe 50pts space in bottom.

Comment: of course! thank you so much!! it was so easy and I'm trying it for a day!